# Can the tag wiki hover text show synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-process

I was looking for tag wikis to edit (on meta), so I went to the last page, where I'll often tags without any description. I see the `ux` tag, which people may not realize means `user experience`. I click on it and I see that I am editing the `user experience` wiki, which defeats the point of what I wanted to write. See this picture for an example:

[image: There are no synonyms]

(I realize that my tag wiki edits are probably only minimally constructive, at best. Please refrain from discussing here, and consider instead making an answer to [my other question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319782/how-can-i-make-a-good-tag-wiki))

It would have been very helpful if the hover text gave an indication that it was actually a synonym. I'm not sure how practical this would be, however.

I can outline several variations to my idea:

- <strike>List all synonyms for a tag</strike> This is a bad idea (I thought it probably would be) because there can be 20+ synonyms.
- List as many synonyms as possible without expanding the hover text
- If there is no wiki, list synonyms
- Indicate tag has synonyms (with link to list of synonyms), but don't list in hover text
- Display the most popular tag synonym on less popular, synonymous tags

Comment: All synonyms are already displayed for tags - eg: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/user-experience/synonyms

Comment: @JonClements I added a picture. You realize I meant in the HOVER TEXT?

Comment: Also, I would appreciate if downvoters would explain

Comment: We can't display *all* synonyms because some tags have 20+ synonyms which would make that box massive, and that doesn't help your situation because it still wouldn't be immediately clear without looking through a long list. Something simpler like an extra line which reads "ux is a synonym of user-experience" would be more useful and wouldn't make the box huge.

Comment: @animuson thank you for pointing out the large possible number of synonyms. What do you think about the other variations?

Comment: @Laurel sorry - my mind for some reason didn't join up the hover text stuff with the "alternate suggestions" - I thought for some reason you meant "in lieu of hover text"... Anyway, I could probably get behind *Indicate tag has synonyms (with link to list of synonyms)* - I'm just not sure if that many people really care as long as their question gets found. It's information you can already get somewhere else if you're interested in the administration side of things, but: "is it *needed*" - I'm not so sure.

Comment: @JonClements Many people simply ignore the hover text altogether. I was thinking that if we made it more useful, then more people would use it. It would also be helpful to have when browsing tags (not by synonym), and might encourage tag edits.

Comment: @Laurel sadly - the people that ignore it - adding more information/clickables I'm not sure will increase any positive interaction. For those that use it - they're most likely to be aware of editing and so forth. Whether adding a link to something that's only a click away from clicking info on... I'm +0 on at best. Just my 2p though.